# Android device monitor not showing anything in tree view in hierarchy view for check the xamarin forms ui performance

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin forms. I want to test the ui performance for android using android device monitor in visual studio 2017 for xamarin forms app. I am able to run the monitor and also selected device is showing but in the tree view not showing anything showing blank how to get rid of it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot about your issue? Did you try to run your code in android mobile phone via USB? Is that normal?

Comment: Yes. I'm using USB cable and running to real device. Please let me know i will put screen shot.